# Emacs merging buffers into one without using C-x 1 keybind

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

Could you suggest the key bind in emacs to do the following:

Steps: for example
 1) I divided all text editor area into 2 pieces with command C-x 2
 2) Then I divided first one on another 2 pieces with C-x 3
 3) How can I make the first piece (a buffer in this case)

See attached image for better description of what I want get[image http://img.skitch.com/20090922-ra1394bnrbsigrdgm5uycjtrds.jpg](http://img.skitch.com/20090922-ra1394bnrbsigrdgm5uycjtrds.jpg)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If i understand you correctly you want to C-x 0 in the window you want to close.

Comment: ... in the *window* you want to close to be precise.

Comment: I edited the post to say that.  Best to use the correct terminology rather than the incorrect terminology :)

Comment: talking of correct terminology, shouldn't be 'in the buffer you want to close'? oh, and +1 for the answer.

Comment: Nopes, should be window (using emacs' own terms), at least thats what describe key says. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

The interactive solution is to put the cursor in the bottom buffer and hit C-x 0.

Answer (score 2):

the other option if you enjoy using the mouse is to *right click* on the *modeline* of the buffer you want to close (the one which shows `helpers.py` in your screenshot). The only thing which you have to note is that you should not click on the file name, as right click on file name is bind to switch buffer by default.

Answer (score 1):

C-x 0 did the trick